# window.getSelection() on mouseup returns previous selection

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

When clicking on already selected text, it gets deselected and cursor appears. 
This is where my problem appears - on mouseup event, window.getSelection() still returns previous selection (range). How to get correct selection (cursor)?

Comment: please provide js fiddle

Comment: At the time of `mouseup` the selection still exists (most likely) - try wrapping the `getSelection` call in a short timeout.

Comment: yeah, that helped, but it feels like some hack - how much timeout do I actually need to be 100% sure it will work all the time?

Comment: Depending on your use case and target browsers, you may be able to use the `selectionchange` event instead. Firefox doesn't support it, however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proven solution:

```
function getSelectionAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(window.getSelection().toString());
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await getSelectionAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();
```

Reference:

1. [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)